# how to write a test for read only Page

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a page emitting XML for outside users.
All it does is create xml from the data. I have a problem writing a test to cover it.
The page is just:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="ListingControler" contentType="application/xml">
    {!feed}
</apex:page>
```

and the test is:

---

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
public class ListingControlerTest{
     Public static  testMethod void VFPageTest_ListForTrulia(){
         PageReference pageRef = Page.ListForTrulia;
         pageRef.getParameters().put('property', 'Shoreland');
         system.Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
         //Instantiate and construct the controller class.  
         ListingControler controller = new ListingControler();
         system.Test.startTest();
         system.Test.stopTest();     
     }
}
```

---

I get only 1% coverage so obviously I am doing it wrong.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the `feed` variable directly in the test and assert that it is what you are expecting. See the example below

```
ListingControler controller = new ListingControler();
System.assertEquals(expectedValue, controller.feed);
```

**FYI**: Controller is spelled incorrectly in `ListingControler`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that tests do not have to cover Pages - tests only cover Apex Classes. So instead of trying to cover the page, look at the controller and ensure that you are executing all the code in that class in every way that it can be executed.

It's probably just my style, but I'd put the instantiation of the controller inside the Test.start/stop block, and would then assert that the generated text matches the text I expect it to match.